# amend table by data.table join

Tags: r, join, data.table

I have two tables

```
library(data.table)
X <- data.table(id=1:4, a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4, e=5, f=6)
I <- data.table(id=1:3, g=7, z=26)
```

and I would like to inner-join one column of `I` into `X` without specifying that I would like to keep `a` to `f`.

If I were to do a left-join, I could simply

```
X[I, g:=i.g, on="id"]
```

without specifying that `a` to `f` should be kept. I look for something similar for an inner join.

Comment: If that means that you want to keep all columns you can do: ```X[I, on = "id"]```

Comment: Apologies, I amended the example to reflect that there are columns in I that I do not want to join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean this

```
X[I[, .(id, g)], on='id']
```

Answer (score 0):

*look for something similar for an inner join*?

Inner join can be done with:

```
X[I, on = "id", nomatch = 0]
```

Or

```
I[X, on = "id", nomatch = 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could filter it out afterwards:

```
I[X, on = "id", nomatch = 0,][,!"z"]

   id g a b c d e f
1:  1 7 1 2 3 4 5 6
2:  2 7 1 2 3 4 5 6
3:  3 7 1 2 3 4 5 6
```